# Unable to access a predefined variable

Tags: php, fopen, predefined-variables

**Hello everyone,**

I was wondering if there any way to access a predefined variable like this..

```
define("EVENT_LOG", "../app_logs/log.log");

function Log($string)
{
   $fileHandler = fopen( constant("EVENT_LOG"), 'w') or die('sCannot open file:  '.constant("EVENT_LOG"));
   ....
   ..
}
```

I keep getting the below error message:

> **fopen(../app_logs/log.log): failed to open stream: ...**

Any ideas what could be wrong? To me it looks as if the predefined variable was not returned as a string (??)

Thanks in advance,
Alex

Comment: First of all, that's a constant. And second of all, check your path.:)

Comment: To me, it looks like your PHP can't open `../app_logs/log.log`.

Comment: Ahh you're right , I had a directory called "app_log" instead of "app_logs" .. Such a trivial mistake :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure that you check that your path is correct and try:

```
<?php
define("EVENT_LOG", "../app_logs/log.log");
function Log($string)
{
   $fileHandler = fopen( EVENT_LOG, 'w') ;
   return $fileHandler;
}
```